# Flask file upload form on the site page error where is my mistake

Tags: python, html, flask

Have a good day!

I'm trying to use the file upload form in the second form on the site page.

I made a route for processing the file, but further (print ('upload complete 2')) the movement does not go. The process stops at - print('upload complete 2').

What can be done to make it work?

It's Flask route with upload code

```
@app.route('/upload2', methods=['POST'])
def upload2():  # put application's code here
    if request.method=="POST":
        print('upload complete 1')
        upload_excel=request.files['upload_excel_2']
        print('upload complete 2')
        print(upload_excel.filename)
        if upload_excel.filename != '':
            print('upload complete 3')
            filepath=os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"],upload_excel.filename)
            upload_excel.save(filepath)
            data=pd.read_excel(upload_excel)
            data.to_sql('rashodi', con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
            return print(data)
    return print('upload complete')
```

It's html page upload code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form class="form" method="POST" action="/upload2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="form_input" class="form_label">
                    <input type="file" id="form_input_2" class="form_input" name="upload_excel_2">
                    <span class="form_text">Change file</span>
                </label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="upload_2" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Upload File</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

It's terminal debug

```
[2022-04-11 22:36:12,738] ERROR in app: Exception on /upload2 [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Appforyou\infovenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Appforyou\infovenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1519, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Appforyou\infovenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1538, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Appforyou\infovenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'upload2' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2022 22:36:12] "POST /upload2 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
upload complete 1
upload complete 2

upload complete
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` does return `None` so

```
return print('upload complete')
```

does returns `None`, please just return string you want i.e.

```
return 'upload complete'
```

other `return print` uses `data` which is not guaranteed to be string therefore, please convert it accordingly that is replace

```
return print(data)
```

using

```
return str(data)
```

Comment: How i may create  two file upload request into one route flask

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index')
def home_page():  # put application's code here
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.files['upload_excel'] != '':
            upload_excel=request.files['upload_excel']
            if upload_excel.filename != '':
                filepath=os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"],upload_excel.filename)
                upload_excel.save(filepath)
                data=pd.read_excel(upload_excel)
                data.to_sql('kotel', con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
                return print(data)
        elif request.files['upload_excel_2'] != '':
            upload_excel=request.files['upload_excel_2']
            if upload_excel.filename != '':
                filepath=os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"],upload_excel.filename)
                upload_excel.save(filepath)
                data=pd.read_excel(upload_excel)
                data.to_sql('rashodi', con=db.engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
                return print(data)
    return render_template('index new.html')
```

Comment: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: <form class="form" method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="form_input" class="form_label">
                    <input type="file" id="form_input_2" class="form_input" name="upload_excel_2">